# How to sort a NSArray which contains NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a plist like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>highscores</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>highscoreInSeconds</key>
   <string>9</string>
   <key>levelName</key>
   <string>1</string>
   <key>name</key>
   <string>Black</string>
  </dict>
  <dict>
   <key>highscoreInSeconds</key>
   <string>12</string>
   <key>levelName</key>
   <string>1</string>
   <key>name</key>
   <string>Black</string>
  </dict>
 </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Now I want to sort this by the `highscoreInSeconds`.

```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *plistDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString* fullPath = [plistDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

 NSMutableDictionary* pData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
 NSMutableArray* highscores = [pData valueForKey:@"highscores"];
```

How can I sort this now?

Thank you very much!
:)

Have a nice day.

PS: It should look like this at the end:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>highscores</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>highscoreInSeconds</key>
   <string>12</string>
   <key>levelName</key>
   <string>1</string>
   <key>name</key>
   <string>Black</string>
  </dict>
  <dict>
   <key>highscoreInSeconds</key>
   <string>9</string>
   <key>levelName</key>
   <string>1</string>
   <key>name</key>
   <string>Black</string>
  </dict>
 </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You don't need to say me how to write a plist i knew that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use this:

```
NSArray* sorted = [highscoreAll sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)^(NSDictionary *item1, NSDictionary *item2) {
            NSString *score1 = [item1 objectForKey:@"highscoreInSeconds"];
            NSString *score2 = [item2 objectForKey:@"highscoreInSeconds"];
            return [score1 compare:score2 options:NSNumericSearch];
            }];
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingFunction:(NSInteger (*)(id, id, void *))comparator context:(void *)context
```

Implement a function which say which of the 2 dictionary bigger in sorting value.

```
NSInteger intSort(id value1, id value2, void *context)
{
    id v1 = [value1 valueforkey:@""];//give required key
    id v2 = [value2 valueforkey:@""];//give required key
    if (v1 < v2) // do comparison based on the data type
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Comment: but i will vote your answer up because i think it will work too

Answer (score 4):

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *plistDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString* fullPath = [plistDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

 NSMutableDictionary* pData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
 NSMutableArray* highscores = [pData valueForKey:@"highscores"];
```

Now use...
You can user `NSSortDescriptor` for this & very easy to use.
just provide the key by which you want to sort the array..

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"highscores" ascending:YES];
[highscores sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
[descriptor release];
```

Hope will for you,

Answer (score 0):

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"interest"      ascending:YES];
[stories sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
recent = [stories copy];
```

Comment: key value is int so how can sort it now?