# How to sort an array which contains Dictionaries?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have an array which contains dictionaries in it; so how can I sort the array according to dictionary key values?

Comment: this question is present in Stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767219/how-to-sort-a-nsarray-which-contains-nsdictionary/4767282#4767282

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If every element in the array is a dictionary containing a certain key, you can sort the array using a sort descriptor. For instance, if every element is a dictionary containing a key called "name":

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
    ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: how to sort int value?

Answer (score 13):

The other way to achieve this would be using `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` method

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [[obj1 valueForKey:@"value"] compare:[obj2 valueForKey:@"value"]];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use a sorted dictionary where the property of sorted elements comes already with the data structure?

Please do check it out [here](http://code.google.com/p/cocoa-sorted-dictionary/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The above shared answer by Bavarious helped me.Just want to add one more thing.If you want to sort a  mutable array  use something like the below code

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName];
NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [[NSMutableArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score -3):

```
 let arrDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "order", ascending: true)
 let sortDescriptors: NSArray = [arrDescriptor]
 let sortedArray = instancesubArray.sortedArray(using: sortDescriptors as [AnyObject] as [AnyObject] as! [NSSortDescriptor])

 print(sortedArray)
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer].