# Sorted UITableViewCell by plist (not name of textLabel)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

All new code, I have no idea why this doesn't work. It loads the table with all my data, not just in order of alphabetical state...

UPDATE: Data Structure added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Rows</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Subtree</key>
                <array>
                    <string>Address</string>
                    <string>Tuesday</string>
                    <string>Information</string>
                    <integer>36</integer>
                    <integer>-118</integer>
                    <string>Place LA</string>
                    <string>California</string>
                </array>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>California</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Subtree</key>
                <array>
                    <string>Address</string>
                    <string>Sunday</string>
                    <string>Information</string>
                    <integer>40</integer>
                    <integer>-72</integer>
                    <string>NY Place</string>
                    <string>New York</string>
                </array>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>New York</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Subtree</key>
                <array>
                    <string>Address</string>
                    <string>Sunday</string>
                    <string>Information</string>
                    <integer>30</integer>
                    <integer>-97</integer>
                    <string>Austin Place</string>
                    <string>Texas</string>
                </array>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>Texas</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Subtree</key>
                <array>
                    <string>Address</string>
                    <string>Wednesday</string>
                    <string>Information</string>
                    <integer>30</integer>
                    <integer>-97</integer>
                    <string>Cleveland Place</string>
                    <string>Ohio</string>
                </array>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>Ohio</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>


- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     if (!self.tableData)
     {
         [self sortedArray];
         self.title = @"Title"
     }
}


-(NSArray *)sortedArray
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle 
                       mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Data3" ofType:@"plist"];
    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray *rows = [[tableData objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Rows"];
    NSArray *rows2 = [[rows objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Subtree"];
    NSString *states = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[rows2 objectAtIndex:6]];
    NSString *days = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[rows2 objectAtIndex:1]];
    NSSortDescriptor *stateDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:states ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *dayDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:days ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:stateDescriptor, dayDescriptor, nil];
    NSArray *finalArray = [tableData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    return finalArray;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Thin" size:24];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[[tableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.section] objectForKey: @"Rows"] objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"Title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Thin" size:14];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[[[[tableData objectAtIndex: indexPath.section] objectForKey: @"Rows"] objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"Subtree"]objectAtIndex:0];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I have 2 suggestions.  1 - break apart your deeply nested statements into smaller, easily debuggable statements.  5 square braces in a row is a red flag.   2 - don't sort the array inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, unless tableData changes completely with every row.

Comment: @Mike I added some code with a separate method to sort them. Please see my question above, where do I use it to sort?

Comment: Do you need to re-sort the same data in a different way for each row, or is it one set of data that gets sorted once and different parts are displayed in different rows?  If it's the latter, sort in viewDidLoad.  If the former, I need to understand your data structure better.

Comment: @Mike, I made another update, and it's the latter. It just gets sorted once per view.

Comment: @Eric - I think you're loading your data into something called "array", but then you're creating your finalArray by sorting tableData, not "array". BTW "array" is not a very descriptive name - it is worth the extra 5 seconds to name things well.  Trust me on that :)

Comment: @Mike I did a full update so you can see everything, I'll stop hassling you, but any help is greatly appreciated. (don't worry about names or memory leak, I got that covered).

Answer (score 0):

In view did load, maybe

```
self.tableDate = [self sortedArray];
```

In your sortedArray method, you're sorting the data and returning it, but never assigning the sorted array to anything.

You are assigning the unsorted data to tableData in the sortedArray method though, which is why you get the unsorted data. I'd take that assignment out, it's confusing.

Comment: that didn't change it. Can you think of why my logs would show this but it wouldn't work? (
    "(California, ascending, compare:)"
)

Comment: You need to look at your sorted array to see if it is actually sorted the way you want. I don't know what your data looks like, so I don't know if your sort descriptors are correct.

Comment: I added the data structure. I'd like to order each displayed Subtree of info by string #6 (state). So in this example, it would be 1,2,4,3 (CA, NY, OH, TX).

Comment: The sort descriptors you're passing in appear to be telling it to sort by the key "California", which doesn't exist. You're passing in the value of the key rather than the name of the key. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767219/how-to-sort-a-nsarray-which-contains-nsdictionary for a solution to a similar problem.

Comment: I'm getting this NSLog on the actual sortDescriptor sort(
    "((\n    California,\n    \"New York\",\n    Texas,\n    Ohio\n), ascending, compare:)"
)